# If Then Else in Terraform For AWS Availability Zones Config in RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

Need a way to grab availability zones based upon which environment:

if env = sbx then availability_zones = "us-east-1b", "us-east-1c", "us-east-1d"

elseif env = dev then availability_zones = "us-east-1a", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1d"

else availability_zones = "us-east-1a", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1c"

`resource "aws_rds_cluster" "example_app_postgre" { availability_zones              = ?????      }`

Answer (score 0):

You probably would want to use a `map` with the [`lookup`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/lookup) function:

```
locals {
  azs = {
    sbx = ["us-east-1b", "us-east-1c", "us-east-1d"]
    dev = ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1d"]
  }
}

variable "env" {
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster" "example_app_postgre" {
  availability_zones = lookup(local.azs, var.env, ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1c"])
}
```

You can provide `sbx`, `dev` or anything else for the variable `env`. If the value of `env` is not in the `map` of `azs`, than the default value will be returned by the `lookup` function.

Comment: Testing that now. Thank you very much!